# about prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing problem with adding single quotes to my query for WHERE clause, but some people suggested to use prepared statement for database and for simple sql query I can do it, but I don't know how this can be done in my situation where WHERE depends on changing array $arr. So, let me show some code:

```
//The $arr can have different options (depends on user's choice) like below and more:
$arr = ["first_name"=>"a","second_name"=>"","third_name"=>"b"]; //user's input or
$arr = []; //user's input or
$arr = ["first_name"=>"a"]; //user's input or other 

$i = array("first"=>"f1","second"=>"f2","third"=>"f3"); //coded
$fName = "first"; //user's input

if (empty($arr)) {
  $where="";
} else {
  foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $tmpkey = str_replace("_name", "", $key);
    if ($value=="") {
      $arr[$tmpkey]="0";
    } else {
      $newkey = $i[$tmpkey].".name";
      $arr[$newkey] = $value;
    }
    unset($arr[$key]);
  }    
  $where=preg_replace('/^(.*)$/e', ' "$1=\'". $arr["$1"]."\'" ',array_flip($arr));
  $where=implode(' AND ' , $where);
  $where = "WHERE ".$where;
}

$sql = "SELECT IFNULL({$i[$fName]}.name,'') AS {$fName}
          FROM tab1 p
            LEFT JOIN field1 f1
              ON p.first > 0 AND f1.id = p.first
            LEFT JOIN field2 f2
              ON p.second > 0 AND f2.id = p.second      
            LEFT JOIN field3 f3
              ON p.third > 0 AND f3.id = p.third
        {$where}
        GROUP BY {$fName}
        ORDER BY {$fName}
       ";
```

The problem with above is that I get sql error in WHERE clause. Is there a way to fix this? How this can be done using prepared statement?

**EDIT:** I fixed the WHERE clause with other solution so it works now.

Comment: `%27` is `'` when it is at the application level...BUT don't do that. Use parameterized queries and build your query dynamically. Put a `?` for every value then `bind` the value. e.g. `where name = 'o\'brien'` would be `where name = ?` then `bind_param('s', 'o\'brien')` or if PDO `execute(array('o\'brien'))`

Comment: Why are you using `http_build_query()`? It's for creating URL query strings, it has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: I used `http_build_query()` this because it was doing what I need, I don't know how this should be properly done and I need help with "parameterized queries". I don't need PDO and for simple query I can do it like chris85 says.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `pdo`? The PHP manual had parameterized examples for both. Look at `prepared statements`.

Comment: mysqli and Yes I've seen it

Comment: Okay...so what's the issue? My `where name = 'o\'brien'` wasn't a reference to how the query should be done, that was just how it would be written unparameterized.

Comment: @chris85 I've never done the prepared statements way, just I did some testing, and can't think how this should be done for dynamic WHERE. I'll try and post a new question when having a problem with it. Finally, I found the way to create WHERE properly from Associative Arrays. I wish people like Barmar weren't so fast with pointing out things but also give it a try to show other solution.

Comment: Maybe the prepared statements will work flawlessly on your first try and you wouldnt need another question :).